# responsive background - css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am currently working on a really simple splash screen for a game I am developing and wanted to just create a responsive background image (not familiar with responsive stuff personally).

I have it working for the most part (in Google Chrome and IE), but the problem is when I open the page in Firefox, the background is pushed up:

[image: Pushed in Firefox]

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body id="bg">

</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body, aside {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#bg {
    background-image: url(../images/bg.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center;
}
```

Any tips on how to resolve this, and make sure the page works in all browsers would be appreciated!

Comment: Apply the background to `html` instead of `body`.

Comment: Still does the same thing in Firefox.

Comment: Then show a live example please.

Comment: http://www.themorusgame.com

Comment: Add a proper Doctype declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
html { 
  background: url(../images/bg.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

### **Tested in firefox. Working fine.**